# nginx log file changing automatically from *.log to *.log.1

Tags: nginx, logging, log-files

I am having issues in nginx log files.

Previously I only made logs to files,

```
            access_log /var/log/nginx/infotrack_access.log rsyslog;
```

I added the following file to my `/etc/nginx/sites-available/alpha.conf` file,

```
                access_log syslog:server=localhost:514,tag=infotrack rsyslog;
```

After I added this line, I am having issues that instead of the file `infotrack_access.log`, the logs are being made in the file `infotrack_access.log.1` .

Here is the /etc/logrotate.d/nginx file,

```
/var/log/nginx/*.log {
    daily
    missingok
    rotate 14
    compress
    delaycompress
    notifempty
    create 0640 www-data adm
    sharedscripts
    prerotate
            if [ -d /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate ]; then \
                    run-parts /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate; \
            fi \
    endscript
    postrotate
            invoke-rc.d nginx rotate >/dev/null 2>&1
    endscript
}
```

When I reload or restart nginx, then for a moment the logs are made to `innfotrack_access.log`, but after a moment, the logs again go to `infotrack_access.log.1`

Why is this happening ?
I have made no changes in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file.

How I can solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run logroate in debug and force mode. `logrotate --force -d /etc/logrotate.d/nginx`. This will show the error messages in detail. Also check the owners of the log folder.

It might be related to this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/nginx/+bug/1450770

Comment: `empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed`, `considering log /var/log/nginx/infotrack_access.log`
`  log does not need rotating`

`not running prerotate script, since no logs will be rotated`
`not running postrotate script, since no logs were rotated`

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer in the bug link posted by `Tux_DEV_NULL`.

Looks like nginx faces some problems post rotation.

So, I needed to make some changes to postrotate section,

```
 postrotate
        #invoke-rc.d nginx rotate >/dev/null 2>&1
        start-stop-daemon --stop --signal USR1 --quiet --pidfile /run/nginx.pid --name nginx
 endscript
```

OR for some, this also works,

```
 postrotate
     #invoke-rc.d nginx rotate >/dev/null 2>&1
     nginx -s reload
 endscript
```